# How to add two elements in one row in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am just learning and coding the same time with Boostrap and the layout I am thinking is something like this:

```
Row
  <SmallerColumn that hold label 1> <Larger Column that hold the control 1>
  <SmallerColumn that hold label 2> <Larger Column that hold the control 2>
EndRow
```

So for example a `combobox` and a `label` that says what is that conmbox for.
For example:   **Country: Combobox of Countries**

Comment: Read the documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal

Comment: Also make sure you understand the grid system: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form-horizontal` class of bootstrap is what you need. However different rows will be taken care of by the `form-group` class. But using a `form-control` class will lead you to have a border around the text as:

[image: form-control class]

In order not to have a border, using `control-label` as the class.

Try this code:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Islands:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
    <label class="control-label" id="l1" >Combobox of Islands 1</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Countries:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
    <label class="control-label" id="l2" >Combobox of Countries 1</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/an197vva/

Comment: Why do you have 2 labels for each? That's confusing and wrong. You should instead use a `<select>` as the other answer has. Here: https://jsfiddle.net/an197vva/1/

Comment: Because the  person who asked the question wanted two columns.

Comment: Labels should be associated with control elements

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri OP specifically said:

"So for example a combobox and a label that says what is that conmbox for. For example: Country: Combobox of Countries".

Comment: @Mike What if I dont want to have options and only text. Should I use select then also

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri If you want to use only text, there's this: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls-static

Answer (score 1):

The question is very simple, but somehow confusing for first timers, don't sweat it, it only requires a quick read on Bootstrap's documentation regarding [form control](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal) layout.

An extract of the layout would be:

```
<form class="form-horizontal"> 
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputField" class="col-sm-2 control-label">LabelText</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select class="form-control">
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputField" class="col-sm-2 control-label">LabelText</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select class="form-control">
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

No need for .row as .form-group will take care of newly appended elements.